# How can I rename a string of character vectors using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame in which I would like to adjust a character vector before plotting it. My data frame, [available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6tyyFIqeUBqOUFMaXB1azhhMVU/view), is 140,000+ rows with approx. 40 labels denoting a location - in this case a local government area in Sydney. Currently each of the names in the 'LGA_NAME11' column are followed by a (A) or (C) which denotes the type of local government area they are. I'm interested in removing the brackets.

I'm currently using ifelse statements to replace the current values with an appended one. To call it suboptimal would be an understatement. I've been writing a statement for each variation.

```
sydneyMapData <- sydneyMapData %>%
    mutate(LGA_NAME11 =
            ifelse(LGA_NAME11 == "Ashfield (A)", "Ashfield",
            ifelse(LGA_NAME11 == "Auburn (C)", "Auburn",
            ifelse(LGA_NAME11 == "Bankstown (C)", "Bankstown",
            1))))
            etc...
```

I'm also repeating this exercise on a larger dataset and R doesn't appear to like it when I have >50 ifelse statements.

I'm interested in trying to find a simpler dplyr solution (mainly because I love dplyr)... and it would improve my workflow elsewhere. I can't help but think it should be possible. In the possible event I am wrong, I'd be open to any suggestions! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sub`

```
v1 <- c("Ashfield (A)", "Auburn (C)", "Bankstown (C)")
sub(' \\([^)]+\\).*$', '', v1)
#[1] "Ashfield"  "Auburn"    "Bankstown"
```

Using your original dataset

```
dim(sydneyMapData)
#[1] 142459     13
system.time(sydneyMapData$LGA_NAME11 <- sub(' \\([^)]+\\).*$', '', 
             sydneyMapData$LGA_NAME11))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.087   0.000   0.088 
head(sydneyMapData,2)
#   LGA_NAME11 id     long       lat order  hole piece group STATE_CODE
#1 1   Ashfield  2 151.1212 -33.89556 85104 FALSE     1   2.1          1
#2 2   Ashfield  2 151.1211 -33.89556 85105 FALSE     1   2.1          1
#  LGA_CODE11  Factor1 Factor2
#1      10150 10-14.99 200-500
#2      10150 10-14.99 200-500
```

Using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
system.time(extract(sydneyMapData, LGA_NAME11, 
          into='LGA_NAME11', '([^\\( ]+) \\(.*\\)'))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.631   0.001   1.636
```

Or

```
library(stringi)
system.time(stri_extract(sydneyMapData[,2], regex='^[^\\( ]+'))
 # user  system elapsed 
# 0.051   0.000   0.047
```

#### Update

Based on the data provided, the below code worked

```
sydneyMapData$LGA_NAME11[c(3,8)] <- 'Other'
res <- extract(sydneyMapData, LGA_NAME11, 
                       into='LGA_NAME11', '([^\\( ]+)')
head(res$LGA_NAME11)
#[1] "Ashfield" "Ashfield" "Other"    "Ashfield" "Ashfield" "Ashfield"
```

#### data

```
sydneyMapData <- read.csv('mapData.csv', header=TRUE, 
             check.names=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your incredible answer. I really appreciate this. I ended up using a combination of `tidyr` and `sub` in my final code. Do you happen to know if there is a way that your `tidyr` solution could be amended so that it wouldn't throw up an error when it encounters a row without '(A)'. The reason I ask is that my final rows feature a label 'Other' which have no brackets to strip and `extract` doesn't like it!

Comment: @vengefulsealion I updated the extract method.  I thought the other solutions would be faster and easier to fix in case of problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `dplyr` solution, is `mutate` not the simplest one?

If you just want to get rid of the ()'s and everything in them

```
sub("\\s*\\(.*\\)$","","Ashfield (A)") # returns "Ashfield"
```

If you want to keep as a separate variable the local govt type that's in the ()'s:

```
sub("^.*\\((.*)\\)$","\\1","Ashfield (A)")   # returns "A"
```

Thus

```
sydneyMapData %>% 
     mutate(local_govt_type = sub("^.*\\((.*)\\)$","\\1",LGA_NAME11),
            LGA_NAME11 = sub("\\s*\\(.*\\)$","", LGA_NAME11) ) -> sydneyMapData
```